# Issue Changing App icon Programmatically on iOS 10.3

Tags: swift

Good afternoon,

I am having trouble implementing the set​Alternate​Icon​Name API available on the iOS 10.3 beta. The app will build and run, but upon selecting the tab to change the icon I receive the following error:

> Unknown class ViewController in Interface Builder file.
>   2017-03-21 13:05:43.406 IconTest[60153:14187202] -[UIViewController setIcon:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd150f03260
>   2017-03-21 13:05:43.445 IconTest[60153:14187202] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController setIcon:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd150f03260'

My code is as follows:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        func setIcon(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
            switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
            case 0:
                UIApplication.shared.setAlternateIconName(nil, completionHandler: {     (error: NSError) in
                    print("error = \(error.localizedDescription)")

                    } as! (Error?) -> Void)
                break
            case 1:
                UIApplication.shared.setAlternateIconName("Test1", completionHandler:     { (error: NSError) in
                    print("error = \(error.localizedDescription)")

                    } as! (Error?) -> Void)
                break
            case 2:
                UIApplication.shared.setAlternateIconName("Test2", completionHandler:     { (error: NSError) in
                    print("error = \(error.localizedDescription)")

                    } as! (Error?) -> Void)
                break
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your target set to iOS 10.3?

Comment: @ AndyIbanez Yes. And I'm using the Xcode 8.3 beta

Comment: It doesn't look like the error message is related to the code you're showing. Do you have a `setIcon` function on a controller?

Comment: @ConnorNeville No. How should I go about setting that up?